# Special Character Appearing in my WordPress Pages Content

Tags: pages, errors, encoding

Can somebody please assist as to why I am getting the following special character � in my WordPress content pages.

Not sure how it got in there.

You can see this special character at this url:

[PPS Victoria](http://www.ppsservice.com.au/pool-and-spa-maintenance)

and then just scroll down to "Restoration and Recovery Services" sub-section.

Any help would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that you pasted something from a Windows environment and that's the `CR` (carriage return, I think) character. I'd go into the editor and just remove those line breaks. That should fix the problem. Also, you might look into standardizing the content type meta tag. You've got

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
```

I could be wrong about this, but in XHTML (the DTD of that page), I think you need to use this structure:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

In your WordPress theme it should look like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply John. FYI, I have placed this in my header.php file. So John, after removing those line breaks manually and now having your line in my header.php file, should I still expect to get these special characters still appearing in the future?

Comment: @tonsils, I'm still seeing the weird characters.  Make sure you clear your page cache.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're manually adding line breaks within paragraphs to control the shape the text. You should only need to use newlines to separate paragraphs. The best practice is to allow the dimensions of `<div class="entry-content">` determine the length of each line of text.

I'm guessing that you copied the text for this page from another source and pasted it into the WordPress editor. Unfortunately, this method is prone to the types of problems you've described. The solution is to use the [Paste as Plain Text](http://en.support.wordpress.com/visual-editor/#pasting-text) or [Paste from Word](http://en.support.wordpress.com/microsoft-word/) features provided in the WordPress editor's [kitchen sink](http://en.support.wordpress.com/visual-editor/#row-2).